Getting this "No pacts were found for the consumer versions selected" when using pact-provider-verifier
I am getting "No pacts were found for the consumer versions selected" when I run the below command:
pact-provider-verifier --publish-verification-results true --provider-app-version "1.0.8" --provider-base-url myCompanyURL --provider "Core.IApi.Cards.Api" --consumer-version-tag '{"branch":"feature\AUTHSUS23-93"}'

I published my consumer contract like this to Pactflow
Pact-broker publish ./pacts -b myCompanyURL  --consumer-app-version="1.0.6" -k IOGckfk69pM3JVOxxZ4vPg --branch "feature/AUTHSUS23-93" --tag "feature"

I can see its updated in Pactflow with these values
And then published the provider contract like this to Pactflow
pactflow publish-provider-contract CardsAPIProviderContract.json --provider  "Core.IApi.Cards.Api" --provider-app-version  "1.0.8" -b https://thredd-processor.pactflow.io  -k IOGckfk69pM3JVOxxZ4vPg --content-type application/json --branch "providerFeatureBranch" --tag "feature"

I can see its updated in Pactflow with these values
So what's wrong with my pact-provider-verifier. Could Pactflow team or experts please help me on this what's wrong here

It looks like you're passing consumer version selectors to the --consumer-version tag argument. That property takes a tag:

Retrieve the latest pacts with this consumer version tag. Used in conjunction with --provider. May be specified multiple times

What you should be passing is the --consumer-version-selector argument. From the pact-provider-verifier help output (taken from version 1.36.1):
Usage:
  pact-provider-verifier PACT_URL ... -h, --provider-base-url=PROVIDER_BASE_URL

Options:
  -h, --provider-base-url=PROVIDER_BASE_URL                                  # Provider host URL
  -c, [--provider-states-setup-url=PROVIDER_STATES_SETUP_URL]                # Base URL to setup the provider states at
      [--pact-broker-base-url=PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL]                          # Base URL of the Pact Broker from which to retrieve the pacts. Can also be set using the environment variable PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL.
  -n, [--broker-username=BROKER_USERNAME]                                    # Pact Broker basic auth username. Can also be set using the environment variable PACT_BROKER_USERNAME.
  -p, [--broker-password=BROKER_PASSWORD]                                    # Pact Broker basic auth password. Can also be set using the environment variable PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD.
  -k, [--broker-token=BROKER_TOKEN]                                          # Pact Broker bearer token. Can also be set using the environment variable PACT_BROKER_TOKEN.
      [--provider=PROVIDER]                                                  
      [--consumer-version-tag=TAG]                                           # Retrieve the latest pacts with this consumer version tag. Used in conjunction with --provider. May be specified multiple times.
      [--provider-version-tag=TAG]                                           # Tag to apply to the provider application version. May be specified multiple times.
      [--provider-version-branch=BRANCH]                                     # The name of the branch the provider version belongs to.
  -g, [--tag-with-git-branch], [--no-tag-with-git-branch]                    # Tag provider version with the name of the current git branch. Default: false
  -a, [--provider-app-version=PROVIDER_APP_VERSION]                          # Provider application version, required when publishing verification results
  -r, [--publish-verification-results], [--no-publish-verification-results]  # Publish verification results to the broker. This can also be enabled by setting the environment variable PACT_BROKER_PUBLISH_VERIFICATION_RESULTS=true
      [--enable-pending], [--no-enable-pending]                              # Allow pacts which are in pending state to be verified without causing the overall task to fail. For more information, see https://pact.io/pending
      [--custom-provider-header=CUSTOM_PROVIDER_HEADER]                      # Header to add to provider state set up and pact verification requests. eg 'Authorization: Basic cGFjdDpwYWN0'. May be specified multiple times.
      [--custom-middleware=FILE]                                             # Ruby file containing a class implementing Pact::ProviderVerifier::CustomMiddleware. This allows the response to be modified before replaying. Use with caution!
  -v, [--verbose=VERBOSE]                                                    # Verbose output. Can also be set by setting the environment variable VERBOSE=true.
  -f, [--format=FORMATTER]                                                   # RSpec formatter. Defaults to custom Pact formatter. Other options are json and RspecJunitFormatter (which outputs xml).
  -o, [--out=FILE]                                                           # Write output to a file instead of $stdout.
      [--wait=SECONDS]                                                       # The number of seconds to poll for the provider to become available before running the verification
                                                                             # Default: 0
      [--log-dir=LOG_DIR]                                                    # The directory for the pact.log file
      [--log-level=LOG_LEVEL]                                                # The log level
                                                                             # Default: debug
      [--fail-if-no-pacts-found], [--no-fail-if-no-pacts-found]              # If specified, will fail when no pacts are found

Description:
  The parameters used when fetching pacts dynamically from a Pact Broker are:
  
  --pact-broker-base-url (REQUIRED)
  --provider (REQUIRED)
  --broker-username/--broker-password or --broker-token
  --consumer-version-tag or --consumer-version-selector
  --enable-pending
  --include-wip-pacts-since
  
  To
  verify a pact at a known URL (eg. when a verification is triggered by a
  'contract content changed' webhook), pass in the pact URL(s) as the first
  argument(s) to the command, and do NOT set any of the other parameters apart
  from the base URL and credentials.
  
  To publish verification results for either of the above
  scenarios, set:
  
  --publish-verification-results (REQUIRED)
  --provider-app-version (REQUIRED)
  --provider-version-tag or --tag-with-git-branch
  
  
  Selectors: These are specified using JSON strings.
  The keys are 'tag' (the name of the consumer version tag), 'latest'
  (true|false), 'consumer', and 'fallbackTag'. For example '{\"tag\":
  \"master\", \"latest\": true}'. For a detailed explanation of selectors, see https://pact.io/selectors#consumer-version-selectors


Thanks Matthew Fellows for the reply. But I am still getting the same warning
pact-provider-verifier --publish-verification-results true --provider-app-version "1.0.8" --provider-base-url myCompanyURL --provider "Core.IApi.Cards.Api" --consumer-version-selector '{"branch":"featurebranch"}'
WARN: No pacts were found for the consumer versions selected
I can see in Pactflow, under Contracts tab there is consumer version and feature branch as passed in the parameters are available.  So what could be the issue now?

You'd need to review the logs at verbose/DEBUG level to find out what's being sent and if it matches what's in the broker.
